# SparkAR: Published Instagram effect not appearing when doing a live stream

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

I am working on a Instagram face filter/effect with SparkAR. It is successfully uploaded, approved and works just fine when across many devices when I try the effect in the Instagram app. I can select the effect when creating a Story however – I cannot when doing a Live stream. The effect symbol doesn’t show up nor can I select it when searching for the effect, while all the other effects are still there.

One user reported that she was able to select the effect during Live on her Android device. But at least on iOS devices it seems to be impossible to find or select the effect.

Are there any differences between Live and Non-Live effects? Or between iOS and Android effects? Has anyone had the same problem before? How can I make sure that my effect is available for Live streaming?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that the use of audio inside the filter caused it to not appear in Live mode.
I removed all audio files and playback controllers and enabled the microphone. It now works.